# 3 days ago, my doctor pressed my belly really hard and I haven't felt movement from my baby since then. Should I be worried?

Tags: health, safety, pregnancy, doctor

The doctor pressed my stomach really hard to find where the baby's head was at, since then I haven't felt a movement from my baby and I'm really scared. Should I be worried? Should I go to the emergency? Please help!

Comment: It seems to me 3 days without feeling your baby during your last trimester is cause to see a doctor, but I don't think this site can answer medical questions.

Comment: Though it is not a site for answering medical questions, I'd rather break the rule in this case to ensure that the OP seeks assistance from an appropriate source.

Comment: SEE YOUR DOCTOR IF YOU NOTICE ANY CHANGES IN YOUR UNBORN BABY'S MOVEMENT, ESPECIALLY IF YOU THINK YOUR BABY HAS STOPPED MOVING.

Comment: How far along are you? If you're early yet, sometimes you don't feel the baby move for a long time. Palpating the baby's head does require the doctor to push around, sometimes hard, but I've never heard of it hurting the baby. Please go see a doctor. In the meantime, drink a tall glass of orange juice or other sugary drink and lay down in a dark room on your left side. Count the number of kicks or movement (or none). Stay like that for an hour. Then you have some hard facts to report to the doctor.

Comment: Do you have any news for us? We're interested in knowing how you and your baby are.

Answer (score 5):

Not feeling movement is a cause for concern and you should **seek immediate help** if *anything* concerns you.

Certainly if you have a concern the internet is the last place to seek medical assistance as whoever responds will not be able to examine you nor will they be aware of your medical history.  Not feeling movement for a number of days should be a cause for concern.

It is very unlikely that anything the doctor did will have harmed your baby, but that doesn't mean that everything is well either.  Your doctors / midwives should have given you lots of information on signs to watch for at different stages of your pregnancy.

http://www.countthekicks.org/ has some additional information and an app which can help you track your baby's movement.